# D3 Chart - Using tickValues for Time Gives "translate(NaN,0)"

Tags: d3.js

In my d3 line chart, I only want ticks for the plotted data. This proves to be a issue with time stamps though as I get:

`d3.js:7651 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,0)".`.

I thought to convert the strings to numbers in the `tickValues` array but I can not since it's got a colon. Any ideas?

```
          // Hard coded data
          scope.data = [
            {date: '12:00', glucoseLevel: 400},
            {date: '15:00', glucoseLevel: 200},
            {date: '18:00', glucoseLevel: 300},
            {date: '23:00', glucoseLevel: 400}
          ];


          var parseDate = d3.timeParse('%I:%M');
          scope.data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.glucoseLevel = +d.glucoseLevel;
          });



          var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, width]);

          var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                        .tickValues(['12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '23:00']);
          // Add the X Axis
          svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying X values as times, so you must also specify the X-axis tick values as times.

As you already have the X values in the correct format, you can just write

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickValues(scope.data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

`.tickValues()` isn't for setting the tick labels, it's for setting where on the axis the ticks appear.  If you want the tick labels formatted in some way, specify a formatter using `tickFormat`, for example:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickValues(scope.data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"));
```

I've used the format string `%H:%M` instead of `%I:%M` as [`%I` is hours in the range 01-12](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format) whereas `%H` uses the 24-hour clock.  For consistency I'd recommend changing your time parsing function to `d3.timeParse('%H:%M')`, although parsing a time with the hours greater than 12 using `%I` seems to work.

Finally, you'll also need to set the `domain` of your scale object `x`, for example:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([parseDate('12:00'), parseDate('23:00')])
  .range([0, width]);
```

The two values passed to `domain` are the minimum and maximum X values to use for the axis.  I've used the minimum and maximum values of your data, but I could have chosen a different time range (e.g. `00:00` to `24:00`) as long as it contained all of your data points.

Comment: Thanks! But I am still getting `Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,0)".` http://dpaste.com/3NPEZ66

Comment: @dman: well, that's because in your modified code at that link, you've moved the code that creates the X-axis above the code that converts the X-axis times as strings to date-times.  As I wrote in the first line of my answer, you are specifying X values as times, so you must also specify the X-axis tick values as times.